# Passing a double pointer in a function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, parameter-passing

I was creating a program with linked lists in C. I created a `head` variable in `main` function. Then I passed it by reference to a function `insert_at_head(struct node **head)`.

I have another function for inserting at tail. In a base condition, if my list is empty, I want to call `insert_at_head(struct node **head)` again. But I am getting confused in passing the actual parameter. Should it be `insert_at_head (&(*head))` or `insert_at_head (head)`?

Personally, I think both are same, because both of them are passing a double pointer. Which one should I use?

Comment: `insert_at_head(head)`

Comment: Assuming that in the function where you call `insert_at_head` you have `struct node *head;` (i.e. `head` is a *single* pointer) then you should call as `insert_at_head(&head)`. No dereference of `head` in the calling function. Without a [mcve] that's my *guess*.

Comment: I tried with a simple program to increase a number's value. Both of the formats increased the value correctly. I think both of them should work.                                           https://ide.codingblocks.com/s/182435

Comment: functionally they're the same thing, you can probably slap together all kinds of parenthesis and `&` and `*` and have it compile and work. There's no point to add any of that here. If `head` is a `struct node**` type and you have a function that accepts a `struct node**` type, simply pass `head`. It's the easiest, most concise, clear code. Anything extra, while still functional, is not best practice and would raise some eyebrows at a code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the `insert_at_head` function, you have to remember that in C all arguments are passed *by value*. That means the value is *copied* into the argument variable. Inside the function, if you modify the argument variable (like assigning to it) then you only modify the copy, not the original.

If you want to modify the original value, then you have to *emulate pass by reference*, which can be done by using the address-of operator `&` to pass a pointer to the value. If you want to do this for a variable which is a pointer, then you get a pointer to a pointer.

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

// Define two global variables
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

void change1(int *x)
{
    x = &b;  // Make x point to b
}

void change2(int **x)
{
    *x = &b;  // Make *x point to b
}

int main(void)
{
    // Define a pointer variable, and make it point to the global variable a
    int *pointer_to_a = &a;

    // Will print the value of a, i.e. 10
    printf("*pointer_to_a = %d\n", *pointer_to_a);

    // Try to change where pointer_to_a is pointing
    change1(pointer_to_a);

    // Here pointer_to_a is *still* pointing to a, it wasn't changed, will print the value 10
    printf("*pointer_to_a = %d\n", *pointer_to_a);

    // Do another attempt to change where pointer_to_a is pointing
    change2(&pointer_to_a);

    // Now pointer_to_a is no longer pointing to a, it points to b and 20 will be printed
    printf("*pointer_to_a = %d\n", *pointer_to_a);
}
```

---

Getting back to the `insert_at_head` function (whose functionality we can only speculate about) I'm guessing it will add to the head of a linked list. It will do that by modifying where the head of the list is pointing.

As seen by the example above, unless we pass a pointer to the pointer, assignments to the head will be lost once the function ends. And this is solved by using pointer to a pointer, and passing the head pointer using the address-of operator `&` when calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the type of `head` is `struct node **`, then you can pass it directly to a function expecting a parameter of that type.

`&(*head)` is exactly the same as `head`.  When the operand of the `&` operator is the result of the unary `*` operator, they cancel each other out and neither is actually evaluated.

This is spelled out in section 6.5.3.2p3 of the C standard regarding the address-of and indirection operators:

> The unary `&` operator yields the address of its operand. If the
>   operand has type ‘‘type’’, the result has type ‘‘pointer to type’’. **If
>   the operand is the result of a unary `*` operator, neither that
>   operator nor the `&` operator is evaluated and the result is as if
>   both were omitted,** except that the constraints on the operators still
>   apply and the result is not an lvalue.

So if `head` is a pointer, the expressions `head` and `&(*head)` are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

In C language, you *can't* pass a variable by reference.

You can, however, pass a *pointer* to your variable. Of course the pointer is passed by value. For example, if you declare a varable `head` which is a pointer to a structure `node`:

```
struct node* head;
```

you can prepare a function to operate on such variable:

```
void insert_at_head(struct node** ptr);
```

Then you call it with:

```
insert_at_head(&head);
```

where operator `&` yield a pointer to your variable, i.e. a value of the `struct node **` type. That *value* is passed to the callee.

Of course, another function, say:

```
void append_at_end(struct node** ptr);
```

can call the former function when necessary, passing it the same pointer it got as a parameter:

```
void append_at_end(struct node** ptr)
{
    if(*ptr == NULL)          /* list is empty */
        insert_at_head(ptr);  /* the same pointer to a head pointer */
    else {
        /* other stuff */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should it be insert_at_head (&(*head)) or insert_at_head (head)?

None of them. They are both wrong and also the same.

If you did the following in your main:

```
struct node head;
```

You will start having problems in your code.

You can make it work but it is the wrong way.

To make it work you must do the following in your main:

```
struct node head;
struct node *phead=&head;

insert_at_head(&phead).
```

The right way to go is:

```
struct node *head=NULL;

insert_at_head(&head).
```